# Cross-Browser jQuery - Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, dynamic

This code here:

```
jQuery(function($){
        var $button = $('#addrowbutton'),
            $row = $('.addrow').clone();
        $button.click(function(){
            $row.clone().insertBefore( $button );
        });
    });
```

Won't work on Firefox but works fine on Chrome & IE.

This is the calling button:

```
<input type="button" class=button id="addrowbutton" name="addrowbutton" value="Add Row" style="height: 2em;"/>
```

Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is necessary to clone twice?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Won't work"? Do you get any errors in your browser console? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes. I need a row that can be dynamically added with a buttom or so.

Comment: You should use quotes in your HTML; they're missing from your class.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? Are there any messages in the console? Show the HTML of the row being cloned. Does it have any elements with ID attributes? You need to make them unique in the clones.

Answer (score 1):

I've put your code in jsfiddle and tested it in Firefox. Works fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/nadjib/X48xB/

HTML:

```
<div class="addrow">Row</div>
<input type="button" class=button id="addrowbutton" name="addrowbutton" value="Add Row" style="height: 2em;" />
```

jQuery:

```
var $button = $('#addrowbutton'),
    $row = $('.addrow').clone();

$button.click(function () {
    $row.clone().insertBefore(this);
});
```

I'm using "this" instead of $button, because "this" is what you just clicked on (i.e. the button here).